# Python - add dictionary via automated process

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a percolation program whereby I check two coordinates and, if they're within a given radius, I add them to a dictionary (A list within a dictionary, if it helps) to show they're connected, via something like the following:

```
def connected(x1,y1,x2,y2,radiusvalue):
    radius = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)**.5
    if radius <= radiusvalue:
                # Search pre-existing dictionaries
                # Create new dictionary and add (x1, y1) & (x2, y2)
                #   or add to pre existing dictionary containing either (x1, y1) 
                #   or (x2, y2)
    else:
        return False
```

However, I'm stuck on the commented-out parts, mainly because I have no idea how to create a dictionary without d = {datahere}. If this cannot be done, how would I go about doing what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: How *would* you like to create a `dict` otherwise? `d = dict()`, `d = {}` both work without data too..

Comment: how about embedded dictionaries? (try writing the answer you want in pseudo code) maybe that will help

Comment: I mean I'd like to create brand new dictionaries everytime there's a connection between points, without having to start by creating x amount of dictionaries, where x is a fixed number. For instance, I'd be fine with the dictionaries just being d1, d2, etc., but how do I write the code to make variables which have varying names themselves?

Comment: You could create all the dictionaries within one central dictionary (each under it's own key value)? Would that work for what you are trying to do?

Comment: It likely would work, but I don't know how I'd specify the key value in the code? For example, at some point in the algorithm, I may come across a pair of coordinates that I need to add to a new dictionary, but, without knowing how many dictionaries I have named previously, how do I know what to name it (d1, d2, etc.)? Is there a way I can put a variable into the variable? By which I mean, can I have code along the lines of "Add to dictionary di", where i is an integer 1 larger than the largest di I have already made?

Comment: @user1939479 If `d` is a dictionary, `d[key] = value` will insert an arbitrary new value in the dictionary. This is the part you seem to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start, but you don't say exactly what the algorithm is for, so this may not be the most efficient way.

```
def add(pointdict,x1,y1,x2,y2):
    # If (x1,y1) isn't present yet, create an empty list of points
    if (x1,y1) not in pointdict:
        pointdict[(x1,y1)] = []
    # Add (x2,y2) to the list of points connected to (x1,y1)
    pointdict[(x1,y1)].append((x2,y2))

def connected(x1,y1,x2,y2,radiusvalue,pointdict):
    radius = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)**.5
    if radius <= radiusvalue:
        # Connect (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)
        add(pointdict,x1,y1,x2,y2)
        # Connect (x2,y2) to (x1,y1)
        add(pointdict,x2,y2,x1,y1)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need dictionaries directly for this problem .

This problem can be solved diretly using union - find data structure , and no dictionary .

Instead , when you implement union - find , you have the choice to do it with dictionaries , but not only.